# How can I see alternative trigonometry solutions on a calculator?

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

When doing inverse trigonometric equations on a calculator, only the lowest positive solution is shown. How can I see alternative solutions (specifically for a Casio FX85ES)?

Current behaviour:
$$sin^{-1}{0.5} = 30$$

Desired behaviour:
$$sin^{-1}{0.5} =  30  
                , 150
                , 390
                , ...$$

Comment: The arcsin **function** only takes values between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ (or between -90 and 90 if you are using degrees). The other values are not values taken by arcsine.

Comment: I don't know about your calculator, but if mine told me $30=150$ then I would throw it away...

Comment: @mac: Sorry, bad notation there, I'll change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your energy would be better spent just taking the value given from the calculator and thinking about this simple observation:

In terms of the unit circle: Note that $\sin(\theta)$ refers to the $y$-value of the point on the unit circle corresponding to angle $\theta$ (Here, $\theta$ will be measured in degrees to match the OP's question, although I think radians are preferably).  Unless the angle is $90^{\circ}$ or $270^{\circ}$, there are exactly two points on the unit circle with that $y$-value.  Therefore, to find the other one, you simply look at the opposite angle on the circle: $180^{\circ} - \theta$.  Therefore, your calculator gives that $\sin^{-1}(1/2) = 30^{\circ}$, and we quickly get the next value of $150^{\circ}$.  To get the remaining values, we add multiples of $360^{\circ}$ to $30^{\circ}$ and $150^{\circ}$.

Comment: Although this doesn't tell me how to solve the problem using a calculator it does explain how to easily solve the problem mentally; I agree that this is probably a good idea. Thanks.